# Jquery Mobile Menu text not showing up on frontend

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress

Jquery mobile menu is generating html of options menu as , and it's text is not displaying on frontend. I am using this on wordpress.
I can see all menu items in source code,text is not visible on front end.
Can anyone please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you share the code thats causing the issue?

Comment: I am using jquery.mobilemenu.js from https://github.com/mambows/mobilemenu.

Comment: can you share your code? there must be something that you might have missed in your code.